# Simple compact special unitary Lie group and dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups

Given a simple compact Lie group, SU($n$) group, for $n=2,3,4,...$,

Can we determine what are the **allowed dihedral groups D$_k$ (of order $k$) realized as a subgroup embedded into SU($n$)?**

What is the restriction of $k$ for given  SU($n$) of

$n=2?$

$n=3?$

$n=4?$

$n=5?$

(BONUS but not necessary: Are there some general rules one can use to determine any $n$ what is the allowed $k$?)

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399916/dihedral-and-quaternion-groups-as-subgroups-of-son-sun-spinn-son-tim?rq=1) with comments.